# Expose a web app on port 80 using Kubernetes and minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm studying Kubernetes using my laptop(no cloud). I started with minikube by following the docs at kubernetes(.)io. I'm not sure what I'm missing since I can only access my web app using high TCP port 32744 and not the standard port 80. I want to be able to access my web app using a web browser by visiting http://ipaddress.

Here is my deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: webapp-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 2
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: nodejs
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: nodejs
        spec:
            containers:
            - name: nodeapp
              image: localregistry/nodeapp:1.0
              ports:
              - containerPort: 3000
```

```sh
$ minikube service webapp-deployment
|-----------|-------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |       NAME        | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|-------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | webapp-deployment |        3000 | http://192.168.64.2:32744 |
|-----------|-------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how Kubernetes works.

`3000` is the port in your container and `32744` is the [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) where your application got exposed. There are multiple reasons for this, one of them is that port `80` and `443` are standard reserved ports  for web services and Kubernetes needs to be able to run many containers and services. Another reason is that ports `0-1024` are [restricted to `root` only on *nix systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only) .

If you really would like to serve it on port `80` on your local machine I would just set up something like Nginx and proxy the traffic to `http://192.168.64.2:32744`

```
# nginx.conf
...
location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass http://192.168.64.2:32744;
}
...
```

Or you can do [`port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) from a non-restricted local post as the other answer here suggested.

✌️

Comment: But what if I am going to deploy a web app in production? Does it mean that is mandatory that we will always have an external reverse proxy outside of kubernetes cluster like Nginx or HAProxy that will forward traffic to the kubernetes' exposed port? I always had an assumption that Kubernetes will take care of this.

Comment: You will use a proxy like nginx or any other load balancer, like AWS ELBs, ALBs if you are running in AWS

Comment: I got it to work using "kubectl port-forward". However, I am not sure if "kubectl port-forward" should only be used during development and not in production deployment. I guess for production, like you said, we can use ELB, ALB or Nginx/HAProxy running in an EC2 instance.

Comment: port-forward is usually for development.

Comment: This doesn't work on my side. Probably k8s change some iptable rules

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kubectl port-forward` for this.

```
$ kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> pod/mypod 8888:5000
```

#### What it does?

Listen on port 8888 locally, forwarding to port 5000 in the pod.

NB: You can also use `port-forward` with k8s services too using `kubectl port-forward svc/<service-name> PORT:PORT`.

Comment: I guess this should be acceptable? `sudo kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> pod/mypod 80:5000`

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work on port 80! However, is this how it should be done in a production deployment?

Comment: @devwannabe, No. You will have to deploy a k8s service of `NodePort` or `LoadBalacer` type to expose your app outside the cluster. Then you will be able to access your app at `NodeIP:NodePort`. Actually there are several options, like using LB, ingress but definitely not port-forward.

Comment: Interesting. That means, external load balancers(outside of the k8s cluster) or reverse proxies aren't really required to expose an app inside a k8s cluster. However, I noticed though that exposing services using NodePort, we can only expose services on tcp ports starting at 32000. I'll check docs for LB and INGRESS.

Comment: I created a new service.yaml file - https://bpa.st/JCQA Even though TARGET PORT showed 80 after running "minikube service ...", the url under URL column was "http://192.168.64.2:30812"